# custom file name for wp_handle_upload

Tags: wordpress

I use the following code to upload images to Wordpress

```
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false,'unique_filename_callback' => 'my_cust_filename' );

$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );
```

but I want to change the filename as what I want. is it possible?

thank s for answers

Comment: Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46758394/change-file-name-in-custom-upload-form/46758542), in case someone visits this page.