# Change file name in custom upload form

Tags: php, wordpress

i want change file upload name and add the name of user that upload it.
This my function.php

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'upload_user_file' ) ) :
    function upload_user_file( $file = array(), $title = false ) {
        require_once ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/admin.php';
        $file_return = wp_handle_upload($file, array('test_form' => false));
        if(isset($file_return['error']) || isset($file_return['upload_error_handler'])){
            return false;
        }else{

            $user = wp_get_current_user();
            $username = $user->display_lastname;
            $filename  =  $username . $file_return['file'];

     return $filename;
            $attachment = array(
                'post_mime_type' => $file_return['type'],
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'post_status' => 'inherit',
                'guid' => $file_return['url']
            );

            if($title){
                $attachment['post_title'] = $title;

            }
            $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename );

            require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

            $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $filename );
            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_data );
            if( 0 < intval( $attachment_id ) ) {
                return $attachment_id;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
endif;
```

i try with $filename  =  $username . $file_return['file']; but don't work.

Comment: what error appears?

Comment: Name the same nothing change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wp_handle_upload` accepts an array of overrides, and one of the arguments is `unique_filename_callback` where you can specify a custom function to rename the file.

Try something like this:

1: Add a function to functions.php to rename the file as you want it, e.g.

```
function my_custom_filename($dir, $name, $ext){
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    /* You wanted to add display_lastname, but its not required by WP so might not exist. 
       If it doesn't use their username instead: */
    $username = $user->display_lastname;
    if (!$username)  $username = $user->user_login;

    $newfilename =  $username ."_". $name;  /* prepend username to filename */

    /* any other code you need to do, e.g. ensure the filename is unique, remove spaces from username etc */

    return $newfilename;
}
```

2: Then in your upload_user_file(), specify your custom callback function in the wp_handle_upload overrides, e.g.

```
    $overrides = array( 
        'test_form' => false, /* this was in your existing override array */
        'unique_filename_callback' => 'my_custom_filename' 
    );

    /* pass your overrides array into wp_handle_upload */
    $file_return = wp_handle_upload($file,$overrides);
```

**UPDATE:**

To get the new filename in the `upload_user_file` function, you can get it from the "url" in the `$file_return` array that's returned by `wp_handle_upload`:

```
$newfilename = basename($file_return["url"]);
```

Comment: @Lutty I see your suggested edit to my answer that adds in the rest of your code - does that mean that its now working for you?

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see if the custom function is getting called? Also, if its not working, then there's no point in adding the rest of your code into my answer!

Comment: there are no errors in debugging, simply uploading the file without changing the name

Comment: @Lutty Did you confirm that your custom function is getting called?

Comment: @Lutty I don't mean did you get errors, I mean is the function actually getting called at all? Have you added any debugging code to make sure, for example add a `echo "<p>newfilename=".$newfilename.$ext; die()` at the end before the return?

Comment: i' m sorry now i try this

Comment: this result newfilename=invoice-1215.pdf.pdf

Comment: @Lutty OK, so now we know the problem is getting the username.  The code works because I've tested it, so (assuming you are actually logged in user) my guess is that your current user doesn't have a last name specified - its not required. Try using `user_login` which is required and will definitely exist:  `$username = $user->user_login;`. Also, their username will be unique whereas their lastname might not be. See my updated answer.

Comment: This sound good:
    $username = $user->display_name;
    $newfilename =  $username . "_". $name;


    /* any other code you need to do, e.g. ensure the filename is unique */
    return $newfilename;

Comment: @Lutty Yes you could use display name either, but remember that the user_login must be unique where display name doesn't have to be! But yes you can choose any of them as long as you then process it to make a suitable filename, e.g. remove spaces etc. Did you see my updated answer that included a fallback if the last name was missing?

Comment: Thaks a lot it is good for me and if I wanted to put the file name as a title in the media library?

Comment: @Lutty you can get the new filename from the url in `$file_return` using `basename`... I'll update my answer!